# Explain this proof of the Wallis product

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Let
$$b_{2n}=\frac{\pi}{2}\prod_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{2i-1}{2i}} $$ and $$b_{2n+1}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{2i}{2i+1}} $$
Show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{b_{2n}}{b_{2n+1}}}=1$$

---

*Proof.* (Credit to uli_rocks for [their solution, pp 224-225](https://www.uli.rocks/understanding-analysis-solutions/main.pdf)) Equivalently, we wish to evaluate
$$\tag{1}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\int^{\pi/2}_0 \sin^{n+1} (t) dt}{\int^{\pi/2}_0 \sin^n (t) dt}$$
Note that since $b_n > b_{n+1}$, $\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}} \geq 1$.
We prove the following lemma: for $\frac{\pi}{2} > b > a > 0$,
$$\tag{2}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\int^{\pi/2}_b \sin^n x}{\int^a_0 \sin^n x} = \infty$$

To see this, let $y_n$ be the value in the limit. Note that $\int^{\pi/2}_b \sin^{n+1}x \geq \sin b \int^{\pi/2}_b \sin^n x$ and similarly $\int_0^a \sin^{n+1}x \leq \sin a \int_0^a \sin^n x$, and note
$$\tag{3}\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n} = \left(\frac{\int^{\pi/2}_b \sin^{n+1} x}{\int^{\pi/2}_b \sin^{n} x}\right) \left(\frac{\int_0^a \sin^{n} x}{\int_0^a \sin^{n+1} x}\right) \geq \frac{\sin b}{\sin a}> 1$$
In other words, $(y_n)$ grows at least exponentially, and therefore must not be bounded.

We now show that for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, we can find $N$ large enough so that for $n \geq N$,
$$\tag{4}\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 \sin^{n+1} x \geq (1-\epsilon) \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^n x$$
Note that, for any $a \in (0, \pi / 2)$,
$$\tag{5}\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 \sin^{n+1} x = \int_0^a \sin^{n+1} x + \int_a^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^{n+1} x \geq \sin a \int_a^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^n x$$
and for any $b \in (a, \pi/2)$,
$$\tag{6}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^n x = \int_0^a \sin^n x + \int_a^b \sin^n x + \int_b^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^n x$$
Find $a \in (0, \pi/2)$ so that $\sin a > \sqrt{1-\epsilon}$, and fix $b = \left(a + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)/2$. From our earlier lemma, we can find $N$ large enough that $n > N$ ensures
$$\tag{7}\int_0^a \sin^n x < \epsilon_1 \int_b^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^n x$$
where we'll choose $\epsilon_1$ to satisfy $\frac{1}{1 + \epsilon_1} = \sqrt{1 - \epsilon}$. This ensures that
$$\tag{8}\color{red}{\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_a \sin^n x > \sqrt{1-\epsilon} \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^n x}$$
and
$$\tag{9}\color{red}{\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 \sin^{n+1} x \geq (1-\epsilon) \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^n x.}$$
We can convert this to indicate that for large enough $n$, $b_n / b_{n+1} \leq 1 + \epsilon$, which together with our earlier observation that $b_n > b_{n+1}$ lets us conclude
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}} = 1$$
On the other hand, plugging in the formulas for $b_{2n}$ and $b_{2n+1}$ in Exercise 8.3.3 (c) into
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_{2n}}{b_{2n+1}}$$
leaves us with Wallis's product.

---

I understood everything except the part highlighted in red(8 and 9). But even the parts that I understood, I only understand how each statement logically follows one after the other (so technically, I can follow the proof), but I can't understand the motivation behind this proof, and how one would think of it. Nor can I really understand the big picture of what is going on. An informal explanation of what this proof is doing would also be appreciated.

Comment: You can directly prove that $(\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{n+1}x\,dx)/(I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^nx\,dx)$ tends to $1$ by noting that $I_{n+2}/I_n=(n+1)/(n+2)\to 1$.

Comment: I don't get why such a lengthy proof has been presented when the short version in my comment is well known.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You have shown that $I_{n+2}/I_n\to1$. How does that prove $I_{n+1}/I_n \to1$? Also, my apologies if it is well-known. I do not know what kind of keywords to search for this short version of the proof.

Comment: Use the fact that $I_n$ is decreasing as $n$ increases (because $\sin^n x$ decreases as $n$ increases) and hence $I_n>I_{n+1}>I_{n+2}$ and then divide the inequality by $I_{n}$ and apply Squeeze theorem.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product and check "Proof using Integration".